# Is IP address whitelisting useful if the IP address is not "secret"?

Tags: security, network-programming, ip, network-protocols

I'm working on an application that will have access to API keys supplied by our users. The application makes API calls on behalf of our users.

The API we're using allows users to whitelist IP addresses that can use their API keys. I was thinking of telling our users to whitelist the app's IP address in order to add a further layer of security, so that only requests coming from our IP address would be allowed.

But I've read it's fairly easy to spoof IP addresses and considering I'm going to be telling our users what IP address to whitelist (meaning, a bad actor wouldn't have to work too hard to see which IP addresses are valid), I'm wondering if this is even worth the effort?

If a malicious actor were to somehow get their hands on the users API keys, would IP address whitelisting really add any meaningful layer of security? Or would this just be a minor inconvenience at best for the bad actor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to send someone a packet with a fake source address but getting the response to route back to you is much harder. In other words if the API requires a connection to be established between the source and destination, limiting access by source IP is pretty effective. Everything that runs on top of TCP requires such a connection. If your API uses UDP (unlikely) and doesn't have a mechanism for verifying the source of the request, then it wouldn't help much.

Also, you might want to try asking the same question here - https://security.stackexchange.com/